# Trying to install wheel package using command but getting this error

Tags: python

C:\Users\lbhanarkar> pip install wheel
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python310\Lib\io.py", line 54, in 
ImportError: cannot import name 'text_encoding' from 'io' (unknown location)